# How to allow a certain domain user to create databases on a remote SQL instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, sql-server-express

I want to allow for a certain domain user to be able to create databases on a remote SQL instance.

What steps are necessary and is it possible to perform those steps programmatically in a C# application ?

Should I first create a login if doesn't exist and then give it the `dbcreator` server role?

Related question: [Safe and secure implementation of logon trigger in SQL Server 2014 Express edition?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284711/safe-and-secure-implementation-of-logon-trigger-in-sql-server-2014-express-editi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would need a **Login** for that domain user to exist first. If all they need is the ability to manage databases (create, alter, drop, restore them) then the server role **dbcreator** should be sufficient.

If you anticipate multiple domain users needing access to this, then you should instead create a **Login** for a correlating Active Directory Group, so you don't have to continually manage setting up multiple **Logins**. You will then be able to map that AD Group to the server role **dbcreator**. (You can even use the built in "Domain Users" group if you wanted everyone on the domain to have access to creating databases.)

As far as how to accomplish this in C#, there's a multitude of ways, and that's perhaps a better question for [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) because it's dependent on how you're accessing and querying your server instance. For example, with **ADO.NET** you could simply write a SQL query to check if a **Login** exists for the current user, if not create it, and assign the role. Or you can even create a procedure that takes in the current user of the application, and handles that logic for you (which will be more consumable depending on what database access framework you're using). But you'll likely have the easiest time managing this by creating an appropriate AD Group and mapping it to a **Login** with the **dbowner** role once.

Comment: dbcreator also gives permission to alter and drop any database

Comment: Indeed is possible to have multiple domain users with the capability of creating databases on remote server. Not all the members from domain users shall be able to create databases, some of them will be only dbcreator and some of them will have the possibility only to have access on certain database and update . So it is possible to first create an active directory empty and  assign the role dbcreator on that AD and after just start by adding users. The problem is that now I don't know for sure who shall be in  that group, i shall give access only after a project is setup .

Comment: @Elena2020 Sounds good, so it sounds like an AD Group is the way to go, and while you're still developing you just need to add yourself or whatever test users you're testing with, to that AD account.

Comment: Any hints about how to create an ad and assign role? It is possible to handle this in my c# app

Comment: Or another ideea would be if possible for me to create the databases with my sysadmin or serveradmin account and then grant them db_owner role.

Comment: @Elena2020 Again I would recommend asking the question on StackOverflow to get the best answers, but [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16171828/5059085) that appears promising if you want to manage it in C#. Though creating the group is something you'll only need to do once, and adding domain users to it is something that's easy to do with the built in Active Directory tools in Windows (and is usually managed by an Infrastructure team). So my first choice would be to not codify that piece of it, rather have your local domain's SysAdmin manage it for you, if possible.

Comment: Yea if you have a fixed number of databases to create, then I'd just pre-create them and not codify any of that piece. And give your domain users the appropriate permissions they'll need. This management side of things is typically not codified because it's simpler to use the tools available to you already, and generally things you don't need to solve with code because they only need to happen once.

Comment: I will have also to implement the following requirement no user except server admin  shall Not be able to have access to the sql server instance and databases via ssms or  sqlcmd. So the only access gate for those users will be through the application. I was thinking about logon trigger but i have no experience with it.

Comment: @Elena2020 Yea that's definitely worth its own question. I'm not sure that's even possible (at least realistically possible), but maybe a **Logon Trigger** and some crafty code from another expert on here could do something, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "remote"? Meaning on the network, just not hosted on their computer?

In general, you don't need to assign *any* elevated permissions to any person or application user. You only need to create a stored procedure that does the very specific steps required for this operation, grant the required permission to the *stored procedure*, and then grant this one domain user `EXECUTE` on this "Create Database" stored procedure. In this way, the domain user won't have any actual elevated permissions. If the stored procedure does nothing more than create a database, then that's all that domain user will be able to do, and *only* by executing that stored procedure.

For example, assume you have a stored procedure like the following that enforces a naming convention of two underscores before and after the DB name (this example also assumes that the objects are in the `[master]` database, which I typically try to avoid, but it does simplify things a little):

```sql
GO
CREATE 
OR ALTER
PROCEDURE dbo.[ExampleProc]
(
    @DatabaseName sysname
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @AlteredName sysname = QUOTENAME(N'__' + @DatabaseName + N'__');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + @AlteredName + N'
    ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::' + @AlteredName + N' TO [sa];';

EXEC(@SQL);
GO
```

<sup>(Note: The database is owned by the login that created it, hence we change the ownership so that same login can't drop the database)</sup>

All you would need to do is the following:

1. Allow the domain user to execute this stored procedure (at this point the domain user will get an error due to not having permission to create databases):

   ```sql
   GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.[ExampleProc] TO [Domain\AccountWhoCreatesTheDBs];
   ```
2. Create a Certificate (this will be used to link the code / stored proc with the permissions):

   ```sql
   CREATE CERTIFICATE [Permission$CreateDatabase]
      ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'UseBetterPassword!'
      WITH SUBJECT = 'CREATE DATABASE permission',
      EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-12-31';
   ```
3. Sign the module / stored procedure (this links the stored procedure to the permissions that do not yet exist):

   ```sql
   ADD SIGNATURE
      TO [dbo].[ExampleProc]
      BY CERTIFICATE [Permission$CreateDatabase]
      WITH PASSWORD = 'UseBetterPassword!';
   ```
4. Create a login from the certificate (this will contain the necessary permissions, and is linked to the stored procedure since the login is created from the same certificate that was just used to sign the stored procedure):

   ```sql
   CREATE LOGIN [Permission$CreateDatabase]
      FROM CERTIFICATE [Permission$CreateDatabase];
   ```
5. Apply the permissions needed for the operation to the principal created from the certificate (the login in this case):

   ```sql
   ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [Permission$CreateDatabase];
   ```

   This permission, granted to the certificate-based login, will be given to the stored procedure, *not* to the domain user! This level of permission is needed in order to change DB ownership to `sa`, otherwise adding the certificate-based login to `dbcreator` would have been fine.

Once that is done, the domain user:

- will *not* be able to execute this:

  ```sql
  CREATE DATABASE [__TEST__];
  ```
- *will* be able to execute this (successfully):

  ```sql
  EXEC dbo.ExampleProc N'TEST';
  ```
- will *not* be able to execute this (due to changing the ownership of the DB):

  ```sql
  DROP DATABASE [__TEST__];
  ```

Keep in mind that when signing a stored procedure (or any module), the signature is based on the code of that module, so if that code ever changes, the signature (and the linked permissions) are lost. This requires re-signing the module to get the permission(s) back, but that's a good thing because it ensures that the code can't be changed without alerting you (or some DBA) that something changed.

For more details / examples, please see my blog posts on this topic:

- [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Server-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/)
- [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Database-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/03/05/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-database-level/)